# Esc button not registering as input in ui prompt

Tags: user-interface, prompt

I have an app script ui prompt that has worked seamlessly for the past year. The prompt asks the user for a date and then runs the rest of the code after checking that they hit the ok/enter button. If they hit the "x" button on the dialog box  or escape key it will close the script. The code still runs perfectly if they hit "ok/enter" button, but all of the sudden the esc key is no longer working. I get the error below. I believe there has been some update to the ui prompts because I noticed that the enter key now works as an input which did not work before, and the x in the corner of the prompt box is no longer there. See the snip below.
Here is another snip of the date code I am running. Again this has worked fine for over a year and I have not changed it. Any thoughts on this error? I cannot find any info on an update for the ui prompts.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vm4Z.png)

[Code Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JMy2.png)

[No "x" in corner of dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSxht.png)

I tried each piece of the code seperately in different drafts and they all worked. I changed the if statement in my code that checks if the user hit the "ok" button, to checking if the user hit the "cancel" button, which is not an option, but just to see if the esc button would read the same as the user hitting the cancel button, this still errored. I then checked if it could still see that the ok button was not the cancel button, clearly the ok button was not the cancel button and it ran the escape code correctly. So I know all the code works, there is just a problem with the escape key not being a valid entry all of the
sudden.